# Wifi switched Elect Hot Water Tank

Tags: electrical

For a vacation home application, I am looking for a wifi controlled/linked switch for the 220v, 30 amp hot water tank circuit.  I see that Rheem makes wifi controllers compatible with some of their tanks which allow you monitor, change temps, etc.

On/off is the only function needed and I would like to be able to use a similar  device to switch a 220v, 20 amp baseboard heat circuit.  Again, on/off is the only function needed.

Thanks for any ideas.

DKC

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of options out there. Basically you need a wifi enabled relay. They all seem to have proprietary web interface/software and various limitations (operating temperature, normally open/closed, indoor/outdoor, etc.). You might want to inquire at a local pool supply shop as they seem to be popular for remotely controlling pool/spa equipment. This is a picture of one brand:

[image]